# Network connections don't work after a restart using NetworkManager

Tags: opensuse, wifi, networkmanager

#### openSUSE 12.3 with Network Manager

**NOTE:** The same behaviour occurs for eth0, but it's primarily wlan0 I'm concerned with.

Whenever I restart or switch wifi networks, DNS resolution seems to be the issue. `nm-tool` shows I have a valid IP and my router's address for DNS, but if I try to access anything by domain name, it fails. I successfully can run `ping 8.8.8.8` (google's DNS) just to make sure I'm getting to the outside world.  The only thing that seems to bring me back online is opening a terminal, logging in as root and running `dhclient`.

Anyone have any ideas what I should check to figure out why NetworkManager isn't working as expected?

Comment: Do you have the wireless network configured to use DHCP on both AP and computer sides?